# Assigning real coordinates to Image map in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am working on a floor map which is an Image, where I want to assign real coordinates to the map, So when I click anywhere on map I should get the real coordinates. I have completed almost everything but don't know how can I assign real coordinates to map.

I am new to Leaflet.

```
var map = L.map('image-map', {
  minZoom: 1,
  maxZoom: 4,
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 1,
  crs: L.CRS.Simple
});

// dimensions of the image
var w = 2000,
    h = 1500,
    url = 'http://kempe.net/images/image-of-a-floor.jpg';

// calculate the edges of the image, in coordinate space
var southWest = map.unproject([0, h], map.getMaxZoom()-1);
var northEast = map.unproject([w, 0], map.getMaxZoom()-1);
var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

// add the image overlay, 
// so that it covers the entire map
L.imageOverlay(url, bounds).addTo(map);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "real coordinates"?

Comment: I meant Latitude and Longitude of earth. something like this. http://stage1876.xn--regrund-80a.se/example3.html

Comment: @ghybs I have latitude and longitude, I want to assign these things to map. So I should get floor coordinates in real time navigation

Comment: How do you include your floor map (image) on your map? With `L.ImageOverlay%?

Comment: something like the code snippet @ghybs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do not use `L.CRS.Simple` and specify "real coordinates" `bounds` for your [Image Overlay](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay). You can just drop all the `map.unproject` thing.

```js
L.imageOverlay(url, [
  [latCornerA, lngCornerA],
  [latCornerB, lngCornerB]
]).addTo(map);
```

Then everything else will use the default CRS and mouse events will generate an `event.latlng` with corresponding coordinates.

Comment: And what about the height and width of Image. Can you please elaborate the bounds part ?

Comment: You have to [georeference](http://support.esri.com/en/other-resources/gis-dictionary/term/georeferencing) 2 opposite corners of your image.

Comment: That is a different question. I am sure you should already find some resources on [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you so much for all you answer. My last question to you is that for creating a bounds I need georeference. What if I get the georeference from gps .i.e lat1 & long1 of one corner(top-left) and lat2 & long2 from another corner(bottom-right) and then assign it to 

var southWest = map.unproject([lat2, long2], map.getMaxZoom()-1);
var northEast = map.unproject(lat1, long1], map.getMaxZoom()-1);
var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156648/discussion-between-atul-verma-and-ghybs).

Comment: That is the point of georeferencing and how Leaflet Image Overlay expects your image in the first place: just specify the actual GPS coordinates of 2 opposite corners of your image. See the edited above post.

Comment: The above code is working but when I give GPS coordinates the map is not visible anywhere. When I give manual coordinates like [[0,0],[100,100]] then it is visible. It looks like it is located in some place. I wanted to to be centered.

Comment: Adjust your initial view settings (map options `center` and `zoom`). You can also do a `map.fitBounds(myImageOverlay.getBounds())`